# change page details based on URL by using if statement

Tags: php, laravel, routes, backend

i am new to PHP but I would like to make the content of the page change depending on the invoice selected by using if statement but I tried numerous ways which did not work out for me since I am using a pdf export package for laravell. my goal is to show different content based on the page url. Here is the controller

InvoiceController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use LaravelDaily\Invoices\Invoice;
use LaravelDaily\Invoices\Classes\Buyer;
use LaravelDaily\Invoices\Classes\InvoiceItem;
use App\Models\Invoice1;

class InvoiceController extends Controller
{
    
    public function show()
    {
        if('http://localhost/Laravel/HotelManagement/admin/invoice/1') {      
        $customer = new Buyer([
            'name'          => 'Ahmed',
            'custom_fields' => [
                'Email' => 'test@example.com',
            ],
        ]);

        $item = (new InvoiceItem())->title('Reservation 1')->pricePerUnit(245);

        $invoice = Invoice::make()
            ->buyer($customer)
            ->series('10')
            ->sequence(10000)
            ->dateFormat('m/d/Y')
            ->currencySymbol('SR')
            ->discountByPercent(10)
            ->taxRate(15)
            ->addItem($item);

        return $invoice->stream();
    }
    else if('localhost/Laravel/HotelManagement/admin/invoice/2'){
        $customer = new Buyer([
            'name'          => ' Abdullah',
            'custom_fields' => [
                'Email' => 'test@example.com',
            ],
        ]);

        $item = (new InvoiceItem())->title('Reservation 2')->pricePerUnit(467);

        $invoice = Invoice::make()
            ->buyer($customer)
            ->series('10')
            ->sequence(10000)
            ->dateFormat('m/d/Y')
            ->currencySymbol('SR')
            ->discountByPercent(10)
            ->taxRate(15)
            ->addItem($item);

        return $invoice->stream();
    }
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('admin/invoice/{id}/',[InvoiceController::class, 'show']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recover URL parameters this way

Route

```
Route::get('admin/invoice/{id}/',[InvoiceController::class, 'show']);
```

Example URL

```
https://yoursite.com/admin/invoice/1234/
```

```
class InvoiceController extends Controller
{ 
    public function show(int $id)
    {
        dd($id) // outputs 1234
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's bad idea to use endpoint like `http://localhost/Laravel/HotelManagement/admin/invoice/1` in this case.
you can use request() for captured invoice ID.
For example:

```
if(request()->get('id') == 1) {      
    // Do you logic here 
} 
else if(request()->get('id') == 2) {      
    // Do you logic here for invoice 2
}
```

Comment: After using this way for getting the URL something weird happened. the URL with the selected id now will result in an empty page, unlike the previous issue which is when I change the invoice id in the URL. the content stays the same